# Content length is 0 for HttpPostedFile object in Itemadding event

Tags: event-receivers, list-view-web-part, item-added

I have a item adding event attached to a document library and as per the framework you can't get the `SPFile` object in `ItemAdding` in an event receiver.

So I'm using `HttpPostedFile` object to get the content of the file.  But there is a strange thing happening here is that when I upload the document using the listviewwebpart using drag and drop I get the file name and the content length of the `httppostedfile` object but when I try to upload the file programmatically like using 
`SPContext.Current.Web.Files.Add` I get the contentlength property as 0, but I do get the filename.  Is there anything wrong with the implementation.??